# Windows client join AD in a specific ou dns driven

Tags: active-directory

given my AD domain as: EXAMPLE.ORG
if I have a client with dns name: client1.hq.example.org

which steps do I need before joining client1 to EXAMPLE.ORG domain in order to have client1 inserted in the "HQ" ou?

is it automagical?

do I need some setup on AD controller?

Comment: As a point of clarification, `client1.hq.example.org` would be a domain member of the `hq.example.org` domain, not the `example.org` domain. In this case, `hq.example.org` would be a child domain of `example.org`. Are you thinking that a domain member's OU placement is reflected in the name? It isn't.

Comment: yes, this clarification helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't magic, you just need to pcreate the computer account in the HQ Organizational Unit.  It's called pre-staging.

Prestage client computers
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759196%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770832%28v=ws.10%29.aspx